# how to use docker container Options inside docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, akka-http

i am using akka http server in my app and mongodb as a backed database, akka http uses standard input to keep running the server, 
here is how i am binding it

```
val host = "0.0.0.0"
    val port = 8080

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(MainRouter.routes, host, port)
log.info("Server online ")
    StdIn.readLine()
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
```

i need to dockerize my app docker closes the standard input by default when it starts the container, to keep it running we need to provide `-i` option with the container like this

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -i imagename:tag
```

now the problem is i need to use docker-compose to start my app with mongo 
here is `my docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  mongodb:
   image: mongo:4.2.1
   container_name: docker-mongo
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"

  akkahttpservice:
   image: app:0.0.1
   container_name: docker-app
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"
   depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

how can i provide the `-i` option with docker-app container 
Note after doing `docker-compose up`

```
docker exec -it containerid sh
```

did not worked for me 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: how is `docker exec -it containerId bash`

Comment: Have you looked at the [list of `docker-compose.yml` options](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) to see if one of those matches the `docker run -i` option?  Or considered removing the need to read from stdin (a little unusual for a server-type process)?